# Back To Basics: Generics in Method Sig

Tags: java, generics

So my code is showing compiler errors when I try and pass the object `Map<String, Future<Cache<?>>` to a method with `Map<String, Future<?>>`. As below...

```
private static void logProgress(Map<String, Future<Cache<?>>> cacheLoaders, Map<String, Future<?>> cacheWriters)
            throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        if (logFuturesAndCheckStillRunning("loader", cacheLoaders)
                && logFuturesAndCheckStillRunning("writer", cacheWriters)) {
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                logger.error("interrupted whilst log progress slept", e);
            }
            logProgress(cacheLoaders, cacheWriters);
        }
    }

    private static boolean logFuturesAndCheckStillRunning(String context, Map<String, Future<?>> futures)
            throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        boolean areStillRunning = false;
        for (String key : futures.keySet()) {
            Future<?> future = futures.get(key);
            if (future.isDone()) {
                futures.remove(key);
                logger.info("{} future has completed: {}", context, future.get());
            } else {
                logger.info("{} future is still running: {}", context, future);
                areStillRunning = true;
            }
        }
        return areStillRunning;
    }
```

This should work as my method should accept a Map where the key is a String and the value is any type of Future.

The below shows I can take a cache loader future and put it into the cache writer map but I can't take a cache writer and put it into the cache loader map because the futures in the cache loader map specify the CacheLoader generic type which "in my head" is a similar concept.

```
            logger.info("starting cache loading");
            Map<String, Future<Cache<?>>> cacheLoaders = startCacheLoading(injector, executorLoadingService);

            logger.info("starting cache writing");
            Map<String, Future<?>> cacheWriters = startCacheWriting(injector, executorWritingService);

            Future<Cache<?>> aa = cacheLoaders.get("");
            cacheWriters.put("", aa);

            Future<?> bb = cacheWriters.get("");
            cacheLoaders.put("", bb);
```

So my question is...can someone explain to me why the original code snippet has the compile error and if there's a way for me to pass both Maps with loosing the type of the values as Futures?

Comment: If there are errors, please append them to your question (e.g. StackTrace).

Comment: @Flown it's a compilation error.

Comment: @AndyTurner Anyways it should be in the question.

Comment: @Flown sure, but don't ask for stack traces in that case, in the same way as you wouldn't ask for the logcat :)

Comment: @AndyTurner My first comment changed and i forgot to also change the i.e.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stripping your example back more, you're trying to compile this:

```
interface Cache<T> {}

static void logProgress(Map<String, Future<?>> futures) {}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    Map<String, Future<Cache<?>>> map = new HashMap<>();
    logProgress(map);  // Compiler error.
}
```

Change the bound on the `futures` map to:

```
Map<String, ? extends Future<?>>
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/JlgOWW)

---

The reason your initial code doesn't work is that generics are invariant in Java: even though a `Future<Cache<?>>` is a `Future<?>`, a `Map<String, Future<Cache<?>>` isn't a `Map<String, Future<?>>`, in much the same way that a `Map<String, Integer>` isn't a `Map<String, Object>`.

If it were, your `logProgress` method could add a `Map<Future<SomethingOtherThanCache>>` to the `futures` map, leading to non-typesafe things happening upon return:

```
void logProgress(Map<String, Future<?>> futures) {
  Future<String> future = ...
  futures.put("", future);  // Compiler error, but let's pretend it's OK.
}

Map<String, Future<Cache<?>> map = new HashMap<>();
logProgress(map);  // Compiler error, but let's pretend it's OK.
Future<Cache<?>> future = map.values().iterator().next();
Cache<?> cache = future.get();  // ClassCastException here!
```

Instead, you need to use the upper bound (`? extends Future<?>`), which makes it a compiler error for `logProgress` to try to put anything into the map (other than literal `null`).

```
void logProgress(Map<String, ? extends Future<?>> futures) {
  futures.put("", Futures.immediateFuture("boom!")); // Compiler error.

  futures.put("", null);  // OK.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining that, it definitely helped.

Comment: Nice. Especially that Ideone link!